# How to get introspect to return information such as email with openiddict

Tags: introspection, openiddict

Is there a way to configure OpenIDDict to return additional fields in the payload for the introspect endpoint call? Curently it only is passing back the fields active,client_id,exp,iat,iss,jti,nbf,sub,token_type,token_usage.

I confirmed that the ~/connect/authorize endpoint principal has the email claim before calling "return SignIn(principal, OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);"

I confirmed that the ~/connect/token endpoint principal also has the email claim before calling "return SignIn(principal, OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);"

Because of the above two statements, I would assume that the opaque token would have the email in it. Shouldn't the introspect endpoint then contain the email information in the payload?

I want to provide an email value for a 3rd party resource server to be able to identify which user the access token was issued to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Application claims - that are potentially very sensitive - are only returned by OpenIddict 3.0 if **all** the following conditions are met:

- The claims are present in the access token. This means you have to assign them the "access_token" destination before calling `SignIn`.
- The application sending the introspection request was explicitly listed as a resource when calling `SignIn` (i.e you called `principal.SetResources("client_id of the API doing introspection")`).
- The API doing introspection was registered as a confidential client (i.e is forced to send a valid `client_secret` to be able to introspect a token).

If you want to customize the introspection response, you can use the events model API:

```cs
options.AddEventHandler<HandleIntrospectionRequestContext>(builder =>
{
    builder.UseInlineHandler(context =>
    {
        context.Claims["key"] = 42;

        return default;
    });

    builder.SetOrder(AttachApplicationClaims.Descriptor.Order + 1_000);
});
```